# iOS: how to find application installation date and update date programmatically

Tags: ios, installation

I am developing one application in that I want to find application installation date on my device and when update happen that date and time as programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can find an application installation date but you could save the current date when the application is first ran. Something like this should do the trick

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![prefs objectForKey:@"installation_date"]) {
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        [prefs setObject:now forKey:@"installation_date"];
}
```

(This code is untested)